# Jquery passing attributes to div

Tags: jquery

I am currently attempting to make the Circle Diagram Jquery by Monochromer responsive to events / changes on a page. That is, if I change a form field percent, the chart updates.

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Customizable-Circular-Progress-Bar-with-jQuery-CSS3-Circle-Diagram/

I made a fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/brandrally/x3ag25q2/

I am not sure whether I have missed something in my code or whether my base logic is flawed, no matter what I adjust, I just don't seem to be able to make it work.

**The Initial Chart setup JS:**

```
window.onload=function(){
$(function() {
$('#diagram').diagram({ 
size: "200",
});
})

$(document).ready(function() {      
$("input[name$='percentages']").click(function() {
var req = $(this).val();

$('#displayresult').html(+ req);    
$('#diagram').attr('data-percent','+ req');


});
});
```

**The HTML**

```
<!-- The Diagram -->
<div id="diagram" class="diagram" data-percent="30.00"></div>
<!-- The Form Field -->
<label><input name="percentages" id="percentages" type="radio" value="20.00" >20%</label>
<label><input name="percentages" id="percentages" type="radio" value="40.00" >40%</label>
```

Comment: What do you want to change? Just pass the input value to the data-percent attribute?

Comment: Looking through code of this plugin there's no way to redraw a diagram.

Comment: @kapantzak Hi, I just want the new value to influence the design of the graphic that is generated. That is, if I click on 20% field, the pie chart is updated to reflect that. So yes, the data-percent field.

Comment: @u_mulder Appreciate your time looking into this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/t6c0txqo/9/

```
$(function() {
   $('#diagram').diagram({ size: "200"});

   $("input[name='percentages']").change(function() {
        var req = $(this).val();
        //$('#displayresult').html(req);    
        $('#diagram').data('percent', req).empty(); // plugin uses 'data' - it's not the same as 'attr' in jQuery
        $('#diagram').diagram({ size: "200"});

    });
});
```

Apart from some mistakes in your code (keep track of ID's on radios ;) ), important thing is the use of **'data'** by the plugin: it's not just an alias for *$().attr("data-something")*, but the current state of *data-something*, which won't change when you update the attribute itself.

Also this plugin is very simple - it's a "one shot", so you need to remove its results and initiate it again after changing values.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your help and indeed the explanation. Sometimes I get things spot on, and other times I am quite off course. Really appreciate the insight.

Answer (score 0):

It look like that you are updating the attribute but you  not firing any event to refresh your circle with the updated value . This API should have "refresh" option :). alternatively you can re-attach this API to the element again.

Updated

```
$(function() {
$('#diagram').diagram({ 
size: "200",
});
})

$(document).ready(function() {      
$("input[name$='percentages']").click(function() {
var req = $(this).val();

$('#displayresult').html(req);    
    var angle = req;
    $('#diagram').attr('data-percent',req).css({
                "-webkit-transform": "rotate("+angle+"deg)",
                "-moz-transform": "rotate("+angle+"deg)",
                "-ms-transform": "rotate("+angle+"deg)",
                "-o-transform": "rotate("+angle+"deg)",
                "transform": "rotate("+angle+"deg)"
    }).find('span:first').text(parseInt(req))

});
});
```